# javascript splice method removing elements from end

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove 2 elements from end using splice method
This is what I am tryed

```
const arr = [3,4,5,6,7];
arr.splice(-1, 2)
```

I am expecting arr to be [3,4,5] but arr value is [3,4,5,6]

wanted to understand why it's behaving like this

Comment: `-1` is the starting index counting from the end. So you start deleting one entry from the end. You would need `splice(-2, 2)`. It is quite well explained in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: read: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Logic should be `.splice(array.length - count, count)` or `.splice(-count, count)`. First approach is always preferred

Comment: you can omit the second argument, `.splice(-2)` is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> **start**
>
> The index at which to start changing the array. If greater than the
>   length of the array, start will be set to the length of the array. **If
>   negative, it will begin that many elements from the end of the array.**
>   (In this case, the origin -1, meaning -n is the index of the nth last
>   element, and is therefore equivalent to the index of array.length -
>   n.) If array.length + start is less than 0, it will begin from index
>   0.

index `-1` means from the last element so in our case, only the last element will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You just start by the last index of the array and remove two items.

The result is an array without `7`.

```js
//                      -1  index
const arr = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
arr.splice(-1, 2);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this will be to use arr.length

```js
const arr = [3,4,5,6,7];
arr.splice(arr.length - 2)
console.log(arr)
```

First param tells to splice from which index it should delete all elements

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr = [3,4,5,6,7];
const itemsToDelete = 2;
arr.splice(arr.length - itemsToDelete, itemsToDelete)

console.log('arr', arr);
```